# Traverse and Replace Items in TreeData

Tags: javascript, tree

I am stuck at the task of traversing a tree and replacing the nodes if they match the key. This is necessary as I load children lazy via REST, insert them into the parent node and then replace the parent node (The node I clicked onto) with the parent with loaded children.

The treeData interface is:

```js
export interface TreeData {
    keyNum:number,
    icon:string,
    name:string,
    length:number,
    type: string,
    links: string,
    children?: TreeData[]
}
```

```
_nodes = Temp array that replaces the current nodes
nodes = All elements 
event = Current parent
test = Temporary array for pushing items when doing it recursively
```

In a first attempt I created this function:

```js
let _nodes = nodes.map(node => {
      if (node.keyNum=== event.keyNum) {
          node = event;
      }

     return node;
})
setNodes(_nodes)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't do this recursively. Only when I open up the root item. In a next attempt I created this function:

```js
const test = [] as TreeData[]
traverseTree(event,nodes, test)
dispatch(setNodes(test))


const traverseTree = (event: TreeData, currentNodes: TreeData[], temp: TreeData[])=>{
          currentNodes.forEach(node=>{
            if (node.keyNum === event.keyNum) {
                node = event;
                temp.push(node)
            }
            else{
                if(node.children && node.children.length>0){
                    return node.children.forEach(nodeInLoop=>{
                        return traverseTree(event,[nodeInLoop], temp)
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

I can finally traverse the tree but the problem is that when I click element1

```
-root
   - element 1
   - element 2
```

this gets transformed to:

```
- element 1
   - subelement 1
   - subelement 2
   - ...
```

So when I click a child everything above is replaced. How can I preserve also the parent when clicking element 1. So that the expected output is

```
- root
   - element 1
      - subelement 1
      - subelement 2
      - ...
   - element 2
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected the code snippet. It is indeed the same. The other code snippet with key got me confused with the React key and I couldn't pass it as an argument to the TreeNode Element. To prevent further conflicts I renamed it to keyNum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a third parameter like in your recursive code. Instead make the function *return* the new tree.

It is indeed a problem that in your attempt the only thing that happens to `temp` is that nodes are pushed unto it. But you'll also need to repopulate `children` arrays in the hierarchy. You can better use `map` for that, and spread syntax to clone nodes with newly created `children` arrays.

Your recursive attempt could be corrected like this:

```
const traverseTree = (event: TreeData, nodes: TreeData[]): TreeData[] =>
    nodes.map(node =>
        node.keyNum === event.keyNum ? event
            : !node.children?.length ? node
            : { ...node, children: traverseTree(event, node.children) };
    );
```

Call like:

```
dispatch(setNodes(traverseTree(event,nodes)))
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked out of the box and is reasonable short. I have never used the ternary operator more than once.